# Why never enter a man’s room in months ending in ‘R’?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

In the movie, *An Affair to Remember*, Deborah Kerr says:

> My mother told me never to enter a man’s room in months ending in ‘R’.

What does it mean?

Why must not she enter a man’s room in months ending in ‘R’?

Any information would greatly help.

Comment: FYI: https://www.thekitchn.com/fact-or-fiction-following-the-120217

Comment: I once heard a saying: "I never drink alcohol, except in May through August, or if the month has an 'r' in it".

Answer (score 29):

The [traditional advice](https://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/297600.html#:%7E:text=What%27s%20the%20origin%20of%20the,an%20R%20in%20the%20month%27.) is only to eat oysters (or other shellfish) when there is an 'r' in the month - that is, during the colder months (in the northern hemisphere).

I assume that the line in the film is a joking reference to this. Traditionally, a mother's advice to her daughter would be *never* to enter a man's room unchaperoned.

Comment: I think you've left out a piece of the joke. Oysters are supposedly aphrodisiacs, so if you enter a man's room when there is an 'r' in the month, and you and he have been eating oysters, he may seduce you.

Comment: There are a lot of months with Rs in them, so it will discourage a girl most of the year, which may be as much as the mother thought she could get away with. I'm not convinced about the oyster idea: it seems pretty tenuous unless oysters have already been mentioned as an aphrodisiac.

Comment: The quote in the question is about months *ending* in *r*, so only the last four months of the year.

Comment: As per the title, someone does have an affair. Must involve a room. The quote is coy, flirtatious, illogical (with a pretend logic) and thus pretense: "Tradition suggests No, but I'm thinking rules are for breaking. Gimme a reason." The character is very *proper*, and the line says "I couldn't." For now.

Comment: @YosefBaskin, your comment gets it just right. But the "pretend logic" wouldn't be nearly as funny without it being an obvious joking reference to the advice for eating shellfish. That in the cold months you would have to snuggle up to keep warm aids the effort.

Comment: @PeterShor Oyster is also an euphemism for the female sexual organ. The advice not to enter a man's room in oyster-eating months could then have a more figurative and, at the same time, more literal meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Although you might expect a cautious mother's advice to be "Never enter a man's room on a day ending in Y," there is some precedent for treating months ending in R as a special category in respects that are unrelated to such visits.

One early jokey reference to months ending in R—that is, to the four-month block of consecutive months September, October, November, and December—appears in an [unidentified piece](https://books.google.com/books?id=uxA4AQAAIAAJ&q=%22months+ending+in+r%22&dq=%22months+ending+in+r%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie6trev-D6AhWXBDQIHfO2DVMQ6AF6BAgIEAI) in *The Bookman* (1927) [combined snippets]:

> Abalone, as you may know already, is the Spanish name used in California for various species of shell fish of the Haliotidæ family, whose richly colored shell yields mother-of-pearl which can be and is used for cuff links, stick pins, vest buttons, the handles of fruit knives and chop suey tables. The mollusk itself, said to be a lovable little animal with a characteristic mating cry, is often eaten by oriental peoples, though personally I deny myself this delicacy **in the months ending in R, as well as those beginning with J, F, M, and A**.

This is basically the same joke as "every day ending in Y."

As for more-or-less serious rules involving months ending in R, I have found at least five from publications issued prior to 1980.

From a [photo caption](https://books.google.com/books?id=Doo4AQAAMAAJ&pg=RA3-PA312&dq=%22month+ending+in+r%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwj9oMHwx-D6AhWbAzQIHRlWBH0Q6AF6BAgIEAI#v=onepage&q=%22month%20ending%20in%20r%22&f=false) in Marthe Troly-Curtin, "Frivolities of Phrynette: Moonstruck," in *The [London] Sketch: A Journal of Art and Actuality* (September 11, 1912):

> ANTICIPATING THE 1ST OF **THE FIRST MONTH ENDING IN “R"**: THE HON., MRS. J. HENNIKER HEATON EATING AN OYSTER. The Hon. Mrs. J. Henniker Heaton, only daughter of Lord Gwydyr, is here seen eating an oyster at Whitstable on board the dredger which went out to the oyster-beds there on Aug. 31 to open the oyster season.

From Anthon Cannon, ‎Wayland Hand & ‎Jeannine Talley, [*Popular Beliefs and Superstitions from Utah*](https://books.google.com/books?id=NRjXAAAAMAAJ&q=%22months+ending+in+r%22&dq=%22months+ending+in+r%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjexcjHmOH6AhWMAjQIHc2HAZQQ6AF6BAgIEAI) (1884), citing guidance from 1915):

> **5868** Don't eat oysters in any month that has an "R" in its spelling (M, S[alt] L[ake] C[ity], 1963); Only eat oysters **in months ending in "R"** (F, Bountiful, 1915).

Clearly, M and F lived by very different rules.

The stricture against eating shellfish in the summer has a (somewhat, but not entirely) rational basis, according to Leslie Bilderback, [*The Complete Idiot's Guide to Good Food from the Good Book*](https://books.google.com/books?id=1Iu7TcHJPDQC&pg=PA14&dq=%22months+that+end+in+R%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi9zfCrnuH6AhX_GDQIHY82CSgQ6AF6BAgNEAI#v=onepage&q=%22months%20that%20end%20in%20R%22&f=false):

> Scientists, fishermen, and chefs have known for years that shellfish can be toxic. Red tide, a discoloration of the water caused by algae bloom (technically a rapid growth of phytoplankton), is filtered by shellfish and transferred to humans who eat it.The specific problem with red tide is *saxitoxin*, a neurotoxin that causes paralysis and eventually death. Saxitoxin has been isolated and designated by the United States military as a chemical weapon. This danger has given rise to popular belief that one should never eat shellfish **in months that end in “r”**. Unfortunately, red tide can, and does, occur around the globe throughout the year.

From "[The Peripatetic Advertiser](https://books.google.com/books?id=GqcGAQAAIAAJ&q=%22months+ending+in+r%22&dq=%22months+ending+in+r%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie6trev-D6AhWXBDQIHfO2DVMQ6AF6BAgEEAI)," in *The Atlantic*, volume 203 (1959) [combined snippets]:

> There is a demonstrably large number of persons—otherwise estimable persons perhaps—who believe that books are **in season only in months ending in *r***. These persons are netted, even throughout the *r* months by suggestions that gift "problems" can be solved by the purchase of certain titles categorized carefully by recipient.

From Alaska Department of Fish and Game, [*Informational Leaflet*](https://books.google.com/books?id=cCElAQAAMAAJ&q=%22months+ending+in+r%22&dq=%22months+ending+in+r%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwie6trev-D6AhWXBDQIHfO2DVMQ6AF6BAgFEAI), Issue 106 (1967) [combined snippets]:

> All bivalve molluscs are susceptible to *Gonyaulax* poisoning but some are affected more easily, due to different rates of accumulation and excretion. The butter clam (*Saxidomus giganteus*) presents particular problems as this species accumulates the toxin over a period of time and eliminates it very slowly; these clams may therefore remain toxic year around. It differs from other species in that 75% of the accumulated toxin is stored in its siphon. A general rule is to eat clams **only during months ending in "R"** as clams, if toxic, are generally least toxic during this period.

And from a [photo caption](https://cdnc.ucr.edu/cgi-bin/cdnc?a=d&d=DS19761119.2.237&e=-------en--20--1--txt-txIN-%252522months+ending+in+R%252522-------1) in the *[Palm Springs, California] Desert Sun* (November 19, 1976):

> FISHING NOT FOR FUN but for profit, carp breeders wade into the "harvest" season near Nuremburg, West Germany. Carp fishing, a major industry in the Franconia area, reaches a peak around the Christmas and New Year’s holidays. Some gourmets insist carp should be eaten **only in months ending in “r,"** when the flavor is best.

Of particular relevance to *An Affair to Remember* is this item from a [review of *Love Affair*](https://books.google.com/books?id=5qU5AQAAIAAJ&q=%22month+ending+in+R%22&dq=%22month+ending+in+R%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiTieC-puH6AhXiI30KHXDxD4UQ6AF6BAgGEAI) in *The Coast* (1939) [combined snippets]:

> Charles Boyer, an irresistable frog of world renown, and Irene Dunne, a Kansas City chorus girl , meet on a Mediterranean cruise, and *Love Affair* promises at first to be quite amusing in a frothy way. Irene Dunn has a talent for comedy and she and Boyer make good foils of the movie's lighter, or pink champagne moments.  “Mother told me never to go into a man's room during **any month ending in r**,” she says to him, which, by the time you figure it all out, is really quite funny. I suppose.

*An Affair to Remember*, released in 1957, appears to have been a remake of *Love Affair*, which was released in 1939. According to IMDB, Leo McCarey directed both films, and McCarey and Delmer Daves co-wrote both screenplays, based on a story by Mildred Cram. Evidently, McCarey and Davies—or Cram—figured that, having come up with a line that good, you wouldn't want to use it just once.

---

***Conclusions***

The original rule about "months ending in R" seems to have involved eating or not eating oysters during certain times of the year. The fact that it appears in a London arts periodical in 1912 and in folk wisdom from a small town in Utah in 1915 suggests that it was probably in circulation well before the dawn of the twentieth century.

Similar rules have subsequently been applied to Alaskan clams (to minimize the risk of toxicity), German carp (for maximum flavor), and book selling (for the holiday season). Applying the rule to proposed visits to men's rooms, however, is evidently a humorous invention of the authors responsible for the 1939 film *Love Affair*, reasserted in their 1957 remake *An Affair to Remember*.